# How to execute python from conda environment by dvc run

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, dvc

I have an environment of conda configurated with python 3.6 and dvc is installed there, but when I try to execute dvc run with python, dvc call the python version of main installation of conda and not find the installed libraries.

```
$ conda activate py36
$ python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
$ dvc run python --version
Running command:
    python --version
Python 3.7.0
Saving information to 'Dvcfile'.
```

Comment: I'm one of dvc developers. Could you please try it out again with the newest dvc version and see if it works?

Comment: Hi @RuslanKuprieiev, nowadays I'm running dvc 0.24.3 and python 3.6.8 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it works! :) Could you please write an answer to your question and set it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 0.24.3 of dvc correct this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem:

```
dvc run $(which python) --version
```

Comment: Do you want to fix the absolute path to your python executable or what?